# Syncfusion Charts in Blazor WebAssembly app

Tags: charts, blazor-webassembly, syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

I'm trying to make the dashboard in Blazor WebAssmebly with Syncfusion charts. However, when I'm trying to display them I'm getting the following error:

[Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHTI5.png)

I was thinking that maybe there is problem in the browser, but I tried to use Chrome and Edge browser and in both I'm getting the same error.

Statistics.razor:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView >
        <NotAuthorized>
            <body>
            <header class="bgimg-1" id="home">
                <div class="w3-display-left w3-text-white" style="padding-left: 5%">
                    <div class="container" style="background: none">
                        <span class="w3-jumbo w3-hide-small">Log in to see the content</span><br>
                        <span class="w3-xxlarge w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">Log in to see the content</span><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
            </body>
        </NotAuthorized>
        <Authorized>
            @if (_statisticsToDisplay.Count == 0)
                                                {
                                                    <div class="spinner"></div>
                                                }
            else
            {
                <div class="container2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 5%; align-content: center;">
                            <div class="containerStat" style="width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">


                                <table class='table' style=" color: black">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="url" style="width: 35%">Worker</th>
                                        <th class="isActive" style="width: 15%">Is Active</th>
                                        <th class="status" style="width: 15%">Status</th>
                                        <th class="duration" style="width: 15%">Duration (minutes)</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>

                                    @foreach (var workerStatistic in _statisticsToDisplay)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>@workerStatistic.URL</td>
                                            <td>@workerStatistic.isActive</td>
                                            <td>@workerStatistic.status</td>
                                            <td>@workerStatistic.duration</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    }
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>


                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm" style="margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 5%; align-content: center;">
                            <div class="containerStat" style="width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">
                                <SfChart Title="Analysis Of Failed Runs" Width="100%">
                                    <ChartPrimaryXAxis ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category" Title="Workers"
                                                       LabelPlacement="LabelPlacement.OnTicks" EdgeLabelPlacement="EdgeLabelPlacement.Shift"
                                                       LabelIntersectAction="LabelIntersectAction.Rotate90"
                                                       EnableTrim="true" MaximumLabelWidth="50" LabelPosition="AxisPosition.Outside">
                                        <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="red" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>
                                        <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>
                                        <ChartMultiLevelLabels>

                                            <ChartMultiLevelLabel>
                                                <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle>
                                                <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder Type="BorderType.Brace" Color="blue" Width=2>
                                                </ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder>
                                                <ChartCategories>
                                                    <ChartCategory Start="-0.5" End="21.5" Text="Worker Name"></ChartCategory>
                                                </ChartCategories>
                                            </ChartMultiLevelLabel>
                                        </ChartMultiLevelLabels>
                                    </ChartPrimaryXAxis>
                                    <ChartPrimaryYAxis Title="Number Of Failed Runs" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Interval="10">
                                        <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="blue" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>
                                        <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>
                                    </ChartPrimaryYAxis>
                                    <ChartSeriesCollection>
                                        <ChartSeries DataSource="@_statisticsToDisplay" XName="URL" YName="numberOfFailedRuns" Type="ChartSeriesType.Column">
                                        </ChartSeries>
                                    </ChartSeriesCollection>
                                </SfChart>
                            </div>
                            <div class="containerStat" style="width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">
                                <SfChart Title="Analysis Of The Duration Time Of The Workers" Width="100%">
                                    <ChartPrimaryXAxis ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category" Title="Workers"
                                                       LabelPlacement="LabelPlacement.OnTicks" EdgeLabelPlacement="EdgeLabelPlacement.Shift"
                                                       LabelIntersectAction="LabelIntersectAction.Rotate90"
                                                       EnableTrim="true" MaximumLabelWidth="50" LabelPosition="AxisPosition.Outside">
                                        <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="red" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>
                                        <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>
                                        <ChartMultiLevelLabels>

                                            <ChartMultiLevelLabel>
                                                <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle>
                                                <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder Type="BorderType.Brace" Color="blue" Width=2>
                                                </ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder>
                                                <ChartCategories>
                                                    <ChartCategory Start="-0.5" End="21.5" Text="Worker Name"></ChartCategory>
                                                </ChartCategories>
                                            </ChartMultiLevelLabel>
                                        </ChartMultiLevelLabels>
                                    </ChartPrimaryXAxis>
                                    <ChartPrimaryYAxis Title="Average Duration (in minutes)" Minimum="0" Maximum="200" Interval="20">
                                        <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="blue" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>
                                        <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>
                                    </ChartPrimaryYAxis>
                                    <ChartSeriesCollection>
                                        <ChartSeries DataSource="@_statisticsToDisplay" XName="URL" YName="duration" Type="ChartSeriesType.Line">
                                        </ChartSeries>
                                    </ChartSeriesCollection>
                                </SfChart>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </Authorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code{
    
    public class ModelTest
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string URL { get; set; }
        public double duration { get; set; }
        public bool isActive { get; set; }
        public int numberOfFailedRuns { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }

    private List<Models.WorkerConfiguration> WorkerConfigList = new();
    private List<Models.WorkerStatistic> WorkerStatisticsList = new();
    

    private List<ModelTest> _statisticsToDisplay = new();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        WorkerStatisticsList = await WorkerStatistics.ReadAllWorkerStatistics();
        WorkerConfigList = await WorkerConfigService.ReadAllWorkerConfigurations();
        _statisticsToDisplay = ReadWorkerStatistics();
    }

    List<ModelTest> ReadWorkerStatistics()
    {
        List<ModelTest> statistics = new List<ModelTest>();
        
            foreach (var workerStatistic in WorkerStatisticsList)
            {
                Models.WorkerConfiguration workerConfiguration =  WorkerConfigService.GetWorkerConfigurationById(workerStatistic.FkWorkerConfigurationId);
                int countNumberOfFailedRuns = 0;
                DateTime? start = workerStatistic.StartTime;
                DateTime? end = workerStatistic.EndTime;
                TimeSpan? calculateDuration = end -start;
                
                if (workerStatistic.Status == "Failed")
                {
                    countNumberOfFailedRuns++;
                }
                statistics.Add(new ModelTest(){URL = workerConfiguration.Url, duration = calculateDuration.Value.TotalMinutes , isActive = workerConfiguration.IsActive, numberOfFailedRuns = countNumberOfFailedRuns, status = workerStatistic.Status});
            }
        return statistics;
    }
    

}
```

My current page looks like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPH56.jpg

Can you give me any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We have created a simple Blazor application in which we are unable to replicate the reported scenario.  We suggest you to check whether the XName and YName property in the ChartSeries are set as the dataSource properties. You can refer the below code snippet.

Code snippet:

```
        @if (_statisticsToDisplay.Count == 0)

                                            {

                                                <div class="spinner"></div>

                                            }

        else

        {

            <div class="container2">

                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-sm" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 5%; align-content: center;">

                        <div class="containerStat" style="width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">





                            <table class='table' style=" color: black">

                                <thead>

                                <tr>

                                    <th class="url" style="width: 35%">Worker</th>

                                    <th class="isActive" style="width: 15%">Is Active</th>

                                    <th class="status" style="width: 15%">Status</th>

                                    <th class="duration" style="width: 15%">Duration (minutes)</th>

                                </tr>

                                </thead>

                                <tbody>



                                @foreach (var workerStatistic in _statisticsToDisplay)

                                {

                                    <tr>

                                        @*<td>@workerStatistic.URL</td>

                                        <td>@workerStatistic.isActive</td>

                                        <td>@workerStatistic.status</td>

                                        <td>@workerStatistic.duration</td>*@

                                    </tr>

                                }

                                </tbody>

                            </table>





                        </div>



                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm" style="margin-right: 10%; margin-top: 5%; align-content: center;">

                        <div class="containerStat" style="width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">

                            <SfChart Title="Analysis Of Failed Runs" Width="100%">

                                <ChartPrimaryXAxis ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category" Title="Workers"

                                                   LabelPlacement="LabelPlacement.OnTicks" EdgeLabelPlacement="EdgeLabelPlacement.Shift"

                                                   LabelIntersectAction="LabelIntersectAction.Rotate90"

                                                   EnableTrim="true" MaximumLabelWidth="50" LabelPosition="AxisPosition.Outside">

                                    <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="red" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>

                                    <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>

                                    <ChartMultiLevelLabels>



                                        <ChartMultiLevelLabel>

                                            <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle>

                                            <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder Type="BorderType.Brace" Color="blue" Width=2>

                                            </ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder>

                                            <ChartCategories>

                                                <ChartCategory Start="-0.5" End="21.5" Text="Worker Name"></ChartCategory>

                                            </ChartCategories>

                                        </ChartMultiLevelLabel>

                                    </ChartMultiLevelLabels>

                                </ChartPrimaryXAxis>

                                <ChartPrimaryYAxis Title="Number Of Failed Runs" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Interval="10">

                                    <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="blue" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>

                                    <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>

                                </ChartPrimaryYAxis>

                                <ChartSeriesCollection>

                                    <ChartSeries DataSource="@_statisticsToDisplay" XName="Period" YName="Can_Growth" Type="ChartSeriesType.Column">

                                    </ChartSeries>

                                </ChartSeriesCollection>

                            </SfChart>

                        </div>

                        <div class="containerStat" style="width: 100%; align-content: center; margin-left: 10%">

                            <SfChart Title="Analysis Of The Duration Time Of The Workers" Width="100%">

                                <ChartPrimaryXAxis ValueType="Syncfusion.Blazor.Charts.ValueType.Category" Title="Workers"

                                                   LabelPlacement="LabelPlacement.OnTicks" EdgeLabelPlacement="EdgeLabelPlacement.Shift"

                                                   LabelIntersectAction="LabelIntersectAction.Rotate90"

                                                   EnableTrim="true" MaximumLabelWidth="50" LabelPosition="AxisPosition.Outside">

                                    <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="red" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>

                                    <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>

                                    <ChartMultiLevelLabels>



                                        <ChartMultiLevelLabel>

                                            <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelTextStyle>

                                            <ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder Type="BorderType.Brace" Color="blue" Width=2>

                                            </ChartAxisMultiLevelLabelBorder>

                                            <ChartCategories>

                                                <ChartCategory Start="-0.5" End="21.5" Text="Worker Name"></ChartCategory>

                                            </ChartCategories>

                                        </ChartMultiLevelLabel>

                                    </ChartMultiLevelLabels>

                                </ChartPrimaryXAxis>

                                <ChartPrimaryYAxis Title="Average Duration (in minutes)" Minimum="0" Maximum="200" Interval="20">

                                    <ChartAxisLabelStyle Color="blue" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisLabelStyle>

                                    <ChartAxisTitleStyle Color="#ed7d31" FontWeight="bold"></ChartAxisTitleStyle>

                                </ChartPrimaryYAxis>

                                <ChartSeriesCollection>

                                    <ChartSeries DataSource="@_statisticsToDisplay" XName="Period" YName="Viet_Growth" Type="ChartSeriesType.Line">

                                    </ChartSeries>

                                </ChartSeriesCollection>

                            </SfChart>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        }
```

@code {

```
private SfChart chartInstance;



public class LineChartData

{

    public double Period { get; set; }

    public double Can_Growth { get; set; }

    public double Viet_Growth { get; set; }

}

public List<LineChartData> _statisticsToDisplay = new List<LineChartData>
```

{

```
    new LineChartData { Period = 2020, Can_Growth = 11.0, Viet_Growth = 19.5 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2019, Can_Growth = 12.9, Viet_Growth = 17.5 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2018, Can_Growth = 13.4, Viet_Growth = 15.5 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2017, Can_Growth = 13.7, Viet_Growth = 10.3 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2016, Can_Growth = 12.7, Viet_Growth = 7.8 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2015, Can_Growth = 12.5, Viet_Growth = 5.7 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2014, Can_Growth = 12.7, Viet_Growth = 5.9 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2013, Can_Growth = 12.4, Viet_Growth = 5.6 },

    new LineChartData { Period = 2012, Can_Growth = 13.5, Viet_Growth = 5.3 }

};
```

}